# Wicket StackOverflowError in Serializing or Seserializing Session

Tags: java, serialization, wicket, stack-overflow

I'm using Wicket 6.15 and I got following exception in my program

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:102)
    at java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(ReflectiveOperationException.java:89)
    at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.internalCheck(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:398)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.check(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:361)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.checkFields(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:645)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.internalCheck(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:569)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.check(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:361)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.checkFields(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:645)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.internalCheck(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:569)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.objects.checker.CheckingObjectOutputStream.check(CheckingObjectOutputStream.java:361)
...
```

I have no idea what can cause such StackOverFlow in wicket-core.

I search for this exception and found that these part of exception are belongs to Serialization. so I checked all of my object and all of them implements `Serializable`

an other interesting port of problem is that this exception doesn't occurs at the first time, It occurs after i try to render component 2 or 3 time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as answered in wicket mailing list, wicket use CheckingObjectOutputStream only if normal serialization failed. i found the object which does not implements Serializable and the problem was solve. but I don't know why StackOverFlowError happens.

Answer (score 1):

Possible problem is that you have self containing objects or possible pairing reference cycles inside objects you store in session.
I'm sorry i cannot comment, but want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to your own observation that CheckingObjectOutputStream is used only after an error: A circular reference should be caught by CheckingObjectOutputStream, but this safeguard might fail if the object-to-be-serialized has a faulty equals() method -- could you check for this?

Other than that, I had the idea that CheckingObjectOutputStream might want to use getter methods instead of accessing fields directly, so a getter method which actually creates a new object every time would produce an infinite, not circular, data structure. However, as far as I understand the CheckingObjectOutputStream code, it doesn't use getter methods, but accesses fields directly, so I think this can not be the cause of your problem.